# How to save uploads models data to the user that is logged in, DjangoRestFramework

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to post data {photos and caption} and I want it to save to the user that is logged in. I get this error 'Got a `TypeError` when calling `Uploads.objects.create()`. This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `Uploads.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the UploadsSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.'

In serializer.save() I put user = request.user as the argument, but that just gives me the error mentioned above. Putting that argument worked in other projects, but is giving me trouble, and I don't understand why even with the error.

Serializer.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [ 'username', ]


class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = False, blank = True)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [ 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_number', 'bio', 'profile_picture', 'banner_picture' ]

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        my_fields = {'first_name', 'last_name', 'bio'}
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        for field in my_fields:
            try:
                if not data[field]:
                    data[field] = ""
            except KeyError:
                pass
        return data

class UploadsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    caption = serializers.CharField()
    file = serializers.URLField()
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only = True)


    class Meta:
        model = Uploads
        fields = ['id', 'file', 'caption']
```

Views.py

```
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = UploadsSerializer(data = request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception = True):
            serializer.save(user = request.user        //I thought this would save to the user but gives error mentioned above
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Edit Views.py

```
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = UploadsSerializer(data = request.POST)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception = True):
            serializer.save(user = request.user)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

but it says

```
{
    "file": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "caption": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}

when I have

{
    "file": "https://...",
    "caption": "hello"
}
```

Comment: Please provide the stacktrace of the error

Comment: I changed my code a little, so now it's saying what above^